# Are there are any studies about displaying user opinions?

Tags: gui-design, information-architecture, interface

I'm working on big e-commerce site (consumer electronics) and we decided to put user opinions on every product page. I'm looking for some studies or some tests about information architecture in user opinions sections (eventually comments sections). Does anyone know some?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more  info about the context.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit question.

Comment: If you need more information ask here.

Comment: Have you tried googling this? There are lots of articles and studies out there.

Comment: Yes, I tried but probably I mess the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nielsen Norman Group has a report on the subject. Unfortunately it's behind a paywall.

http://www.nngroup.com/reports/ecommerce-ux-product-pages-including-reviews/

They have some generic articles as well. Example:

> Reviews can answer questions or address concerns that users have about the product, because they’re written from the perspective of people who needed or wanted, and actually used the product. Offering reviews is helpful, but sites are increasingly taking reviews farther by offering additional information about the reviewer or by better summarizing the reviews. http://www.nngroup.com/articles/e-commerce-usability/

This is a pretty good article: https://econsultancy.com/blog/9366-ecommerce-consumer-reviews-why-you-need-them-and-how-to-use-them/

And, of course, sites such as Smashing Magazine have articles on the subject: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/08/engage-customers-in-your-business/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have access to some Nielsen reports so I will check it out too.